# Multiple arrays in filteredData (MatTableDataSource)

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I need help with something, I have this data in a filteredData of MatTableDataSource

[filteredData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gb0c.png)

So I want to put this data in this two differents tables but it doesn't show me nothing

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Nci.png)

I have this in `component.ts`

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.Groups();

    }

    Groups(){
        this.apiSvc.Cards().subscribe((rsp: any) => { 
            this.groups = rsp;

        });

        this.apiSvc.Cards().pipe(
            switchMap((rsp:any[])=>{

              return forkJoin(
                rsp.map(x=>this.apiSvc.Groups(x.id))
              )
            })
         ).subscribe((res:any[])=>{

            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            console.log(this.dataSource);
         })
```

And this is what I have in my component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table employee-list no-wrap">
            
            <ng-container matColumnDef="#">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.usersid}} </td>
            </ng-container>
</table>
```

So I would like to put the ids according to the image of the filteredData in this order, even with a ngFor in case there will be more data but I don't know how to do it.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyMWp.png)

If somebody can help me, I'll appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. What is your answerable programming question? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - rather than hyperlink renditions of text, paste the text into your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating dataSource in every event:
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);

try to move this to a constructor or NgOnInit method, and just update your data on subscribe:
.subscribe(lista => this.datasource.data = lista);

```
    Groups(){
    /* instantiated once */
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

    this.apiSvc.Cards().subscribe((rsp: any) => { 
        this.groups = rsp;

    });

    this.apiSvc.Cards().pipe(
        switchMap((rsp:any[])=>{
          return forkJoin(
            rsp.map(x=>this.apiSvc.Groups(x.id))
          )
        })
     ).subscribe((res:any[])=>{
         /* populate your table here */
        this.dataSource.data = res;
        
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        console.log(this.dataSource);
     });
```

}

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited the question with the NgOnInit method, but I don't understand it, the subscribe method I have is necessary because that answer is the one I need for the dataSource, sorry but I don't fully understand what you said.